# removeUpdates() won't stop GPS for Android. Setting location manager to null crashes app

Tags: android, gps

The following is my code to get `GPS` within my service.  And when I set the `keepCyclingFlag = false`, then I want to stop the `GPS`.  I had this location service running in my fragment and it worked perfectly.  However, when I switched to using a service, this won't stop calling the `GPS`.  When I tried setting the location manager or listener to false, it crashed my app with a `nullpointer exception`.  I have searched and am lost.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**CODE**

```
public void getUserLocation() {

        user = null;
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
                this.LOCATION_SERVICE);



        locationListener = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                if (location.getAccuracy() < 100) {
                    gpsSignalReceived = true;

                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lon = location.getLongitude();


                    LatLng objLatLon = new LatLng(lat, lon);



                if (!keepCyclingFlag){//if this flag is false then stop the GPS
                    lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);

                    lm = null;
                    Log.d("byi", "GPS SHOULD STOP");
                }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        };

        bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        //Log.d("BYI", "Providers: " + lm.getProviders(true));
                //lm.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, locationListener);
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
                lm.requestLocationUpdates(lm.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are abusing the LocationManager just a little, by registering same listener twice.
I would try 2 things:

1. register 2 different instances of listeners.
2. call the removeUpdates twice with the same instance.

Comment: I am stupid and was accidentally calling the service twice.  After much headache I solved it and had nothing to do with the location manager.  However, to make my code cleaner I did do #1.  Created a class that implements LocationListener and then created two instances of that.  Thanks